# Raoult's Law and Mole Fraction

Tags: physical-chemistry, solutions, concentration, mole, vapor-pressure

Raoult's Law states that the partial vapor pressure of each component of an ideal mixture of liquids is equal to the vapor pressure of the pure component multiplied by its mole fraction in the mixture.

As we know that the liquid and vapour in a container are at dynamic equilibrium,

So the mole fraction which is mentioned in Raoult's Law is measured at equilibrium or initially?

Answer (score 3):

Raoults Law says that, for an ideal liquid mixture, the partial pressure of each component **in the gas phase** is equal to the vapor pressure of the pure component (at the temperature of the system) times the  mole fraction of that component in the liquid phase.  If the system is at equilibrium, the mole fraction to use in the equation is the **current** mole fraction.

Comment: So you want to say that if we have to calculate partial pressure at any time then we must use mole fraction of the component in solution at that time in the equation?

Comment: Yes, that is what I’m saying.

Comment: But that creates a problem, Initially partial pressure is zero but the product vapor pressure  as a pure component and mole fraction is not equal to zero, leading to a contradiction to your statement

Comment: Why is the partial pressure zero initially?  Do you now have vapor and liquid initially at equilibrium?

Comment: Initially partial pressure will be zero as nothing will have been evaporated from solution

Comment: This is a non-equilibriium situation, and Raoult's law applies only to equilibrium.  However, at the interface between the liquid and gas phases, the local partial pressures equilibrate instantaneously with the liquid at the interface, so it always applies at the interface.  It's just that, if the global system is not at equilibrium, the partial pressure in the gas phase vary with distance from the interface, and diffusion is occurring in the gas phase.

Comment: But as you say that to calculate partial pressure at any time then we must use mole fraction of the component in solution at that time in the equation, then that statement is also incorrect since we will not have equilibrium every time

Comment: In a transient situation, the equilibrium relationship applies only at the interface.

Comment: Ok So When we have reached saturated conditions, we take the mole fraction components of solution of that time i.e when liquid-vapour equilibrium is achieved

Comment: Globally, yes.  At the interface, the local concentrations in the liquid and vapor phases are always at instantaneous equilibrium.

Comment: Can I have a discussion with you in chat to tell you the question  related to this which caused all confusion?