# Raoult's Law confusion

Tags: physical-chemistry

I have this confusion regarding the statement of Raoult's Law. It states that

> The partial pressure of each component of an ideal mixture of liquids is equal to the vapour pressure of the pure component multiplied by its mole fraction in the mixture.

Does mole fraction in the mixture mean the combined liquid-vapour mixture or only the liquid which is left after evaporation on attaining equilibrium?

I had this problem in my textbook, one mole of two volatile substances each is mixed. Pure pressures of both of them are given. Should I just use mole fraction as one-half? Aren't some of the moles gonna go into vapour phase?

Comment: For the  liquid-vapour mixture to be at equilibrium, the concentrations in the vapor phase and the liquid phase would have to be stable.

Comment: Let me put it this way: does the vapour pressure of a mixture depend on how much amount (preferably in moles) of volatile components you put in a closed vessel, or on how much amount of that, which you put, is left in the liquid phase after equilibrium vapour pressure is attained.

Comment: You must have heard about the mass conservation law. Gas cannot contain more than you have put there.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like:

> The **saturated** partial pressure of each component of an ideal mixture of liquids is equal to the **saturated** vapour pressure of the pure component multiplied by its mole fraction in the **liquid phase at equilibrium**.

The Raoult law relates to an equilibrium state. Therefore saturated partial pressures of components in gaseous phase relate themselves to respective mole fractions of the equilibrium liquid phase composition.

Comment: So, how would you answer the question I mentioned I have in my textbook?

Comment: I intuitively thought that the mole fraction **in liquid** will be favoured for the component which is less volatile. Thus, the one-half mole fraction would be changed. But the solution uses the mole fraction of the amount initially put in, which confused me in the first place. This is the very reason I asked the question. Could you tell me if I'm correct in my intuition? Could you summarize it all in one sentence? (Solution = textbook answer, no pun intended)

Comment: It was Benzene and Toulene. How am I supposed to know if the gas phase volume is comparable to the liquid or not?

Comment: As a complete side note, if they volumes were comparable, how would I calculate the amount that evaporated?

Comment: _The saturated partial pressure of each component of an ideal mixture of liquids is equal to the saturated vapour pressure of the pure component multiplied by its mole fraction in the liquid mixture._ What is this mole fraction? The initial one or when liquid-vapour equilibrium is achieved

Comment: @Lllt How long have you been thinking about that? Few minutes  should be more than enough. I will let you extra time.

Comment: @Poutnik you say thinking, I have given a week to this question thinking , discussing, questioning but not explanation

Comment: See this https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44773/raoults-law-and-mole-fraction?rq=1

Comment: @Poutnik I think that it should be the one when liquid-vapour equilibrium is achieved but there are many questions which make me doubt my thought

Comment: @Lllt Became an advocate of both versions, collect evidence speaking for each case and accusations against them. The see which side wins.

Comment: @Poutnik Ok I will become advocate for both sides  but can you be the judge so that you could decide are my evidences true or false , accusations correct or incorrect and tell which side has more stronger claims :-)

Comment: @Lllt I will not. The whole sense in it is for **you** to get sure about the answer, not that you are told which one it is. As it is a trivial thought exercise. // Do phase compositions at equilibrium mutually relate to initial or current compositions ?

Comment: The equilibrium constant for the reaction gives the Concentrations or mole fractions at equilibrium in both the liquid and vapor phases

Comment: @jimchmst What reaction ?